# Further Scale CSS Background Cover Property

Tags: css, css-filters

I have a splash image that is set as a background to a containing `<div>` via CSS. The element style is currently set as follows:

```
#splash{
    background: url('image');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

This is all fine except for the `filter:blur(5px)` line. This leaves a 5 pixel "soft edge" around the image show here:

[Example of soft edge on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER50i.png)

If I can further cover the `<div>` by 5px, I will achieve the same blur effect and maintain a sharp edge.

I can re-position the image render point and "cheat-it-over" a bit, but I want to know if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with it a little and just found a working solution which doesn't even require touching the html. It works by stacking two generated elements via `:before` and `:after`. It does require you to add `overflow: hidden;` to your `div#splash` because otherwise the blurred image exceeds the container boundaries, and also `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` to make the absolute positioning and "sizing" of the pseudo elements work.

```css
#splash {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
}
#splash:before {
  border: 5px solid white; // user the corresponding backgroundcolor of your page here
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
#splash:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/280);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrBVrp

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten around to implementing it, but I checked out your pen. It seems to be the best solution that I've come across. Thanks for the help.